# AXIOS request with X-Auth-Token

Tags: javascript, api, axios

How can i set the token created from the 1st request & use in the next? Tried setting both as `"X-Auth-Token": clientToken` or Authorization: `Bearer ${clientToken}`, still it doesn't work.

Getting an error stating:

```
data: {
      description: "Missing request header 'X-Auth-Token' for method parameter of type String"
}
```

This is the request

```
axios
.post(tokenUrl, credentials, {
    headers: { "content-type": "application/json" }
})
.then(function(response) {
    const clientToken = response.data;
    console.log(clientToken);
    console.log("fetched token via api");

    //Get Receipt data
    const receiptUrl =
        "http://rest/financial/receipt";
    const dateRange = {
        params: {
            from: "2020-03-12",
            to: "2020-03-13"
        }
    };

    const header = {
        headers: {
            "X-Auth-Token": clientToken,
            "content-type": "application/json"
        }
    };
    axios
        .get(receiptUrl, dateRange, header)
        .then(function(response) {
            console.log(response.data);
            console.log("fetched receipts via api");
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: Pass token in headers as bearer token: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try something like this:

```
// Other code...

let data = {
    params: {
        from: "2020-03-12",
        to: "2020-03-13"
    },
    headers: {
        "X-Auth-Token": clientToken,
        "content-type": "application/json"
    }
};

axios.get(receiptUrl, data).then(function(response) {
    // ...
}).catch(function(error) {
    //...
});
```

Check the [get](https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosgeturl-config) method signature, which is:

```
axios.get(URL, { params:{}, headers: { key: 'value' } })
```

Answer (score 4):

Try Setting the token in the default headers, if the token exists

```
if (clientToken) {
    axios.defaults.headers.common["x-auth-token"] = clientToken;
  } else {
    delete axios.defaults.headers.common["x-auth-token"];
  }

  const header = {
     headers: {
       "content-type": "application/json"
        }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `clientToken` globally:

```
const JWT_TOKEN = 'jwt_access_token';

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: apiURL,
  timeout: 5 * 60 * 1000,
});

if (localStorage.getItem(JWT_TOKEN)) {
  const token = localStorage.getItem(JWT_TOKEN);
  api.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = `Bearer ${clientToken}`;
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong byt "X-Auth-Token" is not the same as "Authorization' header.So I am pretty sure the code above will not work

Comment: Hi, would like to understand too, in what scenarios do we normally consider setting this in default? 
In my current case the token is only required once for the next following request, does it make sense to keep this globally?

Comment: ya i'm tried using Authorization: Bearer ${clientToken} seems it's different with X-Auth-Token